# Snowflake SQL - Select the rows of a column where the values contain at least one alphabet

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I tried using this code but no rows are getting selected.

```
select column
from table
where column like '%[a-z]%';
```

In the output, I am expecting all the rows where the value contains at least one alphabet. The column consists of values like 52813897, 52813883, 262556854, r9av145, 2z5pgnw, 262729215, eunjh65.

Comment: The SQL LIKE command does not support "ranges" like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `RLIKE`:

```
select column
from table
where RLIKE(column, '.*[a-z].*');
```

`RLIKE(column, '.*[a-z].*', 'i')` could be use for case-insensitve match.

Comment: Thank you! This seems to be only query that is returning the response I was expecting. Would you mind explaining why it is necessary to use the period in the expression?

Comment: @apramod `.*` means any number of characters, it works kind of `%` for LIKE

Answer (score 1):

You need something like this :

```
  DECLARE @Table TABLE(
            Col VARCHAR(50)
    )
    
    INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 'ABC' 
    INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 'Italy' 
    INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 'Apple1' 
    INSERT INTO @Table SELECT '234.62' 
    INSERT INTO @Table SELECT '2:234:43:22' 
    INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 'France' 
    INSERT INTO @Table SELECT '6435.23'
    INSERT INTO @Table SELECT '2' 
    INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 'Lions'
    

SELECT * FROM @Table WHERE Col  LIKE '%[a-z]%'  -- you can use it
```

The result will be displayed for all row with caintans a-z

And looks like : [image]

Comment: I believe that was the same query I was trying. It is not returning any rows for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

You need a regular expression:

```
where col rlike '[a-z]'
```

Note:  depending on the collation, this might only look for lower-case letters, so you might want:

```
where col rlike '[a-zA-Z]'
```

Or for any non-digit:

```
where col rlike '[^0-9]'
```

Or if you want to be more general:

```
where col rlike '[[:alpha:]]'
```

Or for any non-digit:

```
where col rlike '[^0-9]'
```

Comment: I tried this, but it is similarly giving me no output. No rows are getting selected.

Comment: @apramod . . . If that is the case, then the characters that look like letters really are not standard alpha characters.  But do not despair, you can look for non-digits as in the final suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You could try cast:

```
select col from Table where CAST(col as varchar) Like '%[a-z]%'
```

or

```
select col from Table where CAST(col as nvarchar) Like '%[a-z]%'
```